# Уведомление с кнопкой в линукс с использованием python3

Tags: python, linux

[image: Воть]
Возможно ли сделать уведомление с кнопкой с помощью python 3 или средствами linux?

Использую Manjaro

Comment: Системное уведомление в линукс. Обновил пост.

Comment: https://blog.abhi.host/blog/2011/09/08/adding-buttons-while-using-python/

Comment: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gio-2.0/classes/Notification.html

Comment: andreymal, первый вариант для python 2 же, а второй для Gnome только?

Comment: есть подозрение, что первый вариант очень легко портируется на нужный питон

Comment: Спасибо большое) видимо надо учиться гуглить

Comment: @boggaar второй вариант работает не только в гном. уведомление отправляется в дбас, а там уже и кеды и гном его принимают. но будет кнопка в уведомлении или нет очень зависит от того какой системой оно рисуется. на убунте например долгое время уведомления не позволяли вставлять кнопки